# Cursor variable not updated

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm not understanding why the variable, @NextURLId, in this cursor is not being updated. Here is the code

```
DECLARE @NextURLId INT = 1
DECLARE @varContact_Id INT

DECLARE GetURL_Cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT(contact_id)
    FROM obp.Contacts
OPEN GetURL_Cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM GetURL_Cursor INTO @varContact_id
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
-- Available URLs have the used value as NULL. Used has value of 1.
SET @NextURLId = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM obp.URL WHERE used IS NULL)

UPDATE obp.Contacts SET URL = (
    SELECT url from obp.URL WHERE id = @NextURLId)
UPDATE obp.URL SET  
    used = 1,
    contact_id = @varContact_Id,
    date = GETDATE()
 WHERE id = @NextURLId

FETCH NEXT FROM GetURL_Cursor INTO @varContact_id
END;

CLOSE GetURL_Cursor
DEALLOCATE GetURL_Cursor
```

The code is supposed to retrieve a unique URL from a table (obp.URL), enter that URL in the Contacts table and then update the URL to indicated that the URL has been used. It seems to me that after the URL table is updated with 'used = 1' then the next iteration of the code should get a new URLId when I query for it.

However, when I run this code I get the same URL every time. No doubt I am missing something obvious but need some help to point it out.

As a side, if there is a set based solution for this, I'd be happy to hear it.

TIA

Comment: Am I right to assume that you try to randomly associate a URLId with a ContactID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this

```
UPDATE obp.Contacts SET URL = (
    SELECT url from obp.URL WHERE id = @NextURLId)
```

updates *every* row with the same. Add a proper WHERE clause like

```
WHERE contact_id=@varContact_id
```

About the requirement for this: I understand that you want to associate a Contact with a URL and that there is no logical rule for which with what. At first sight I would consider a match table the right way to do this. It feels better to me to put such associations into a seperate table, even if there is a strong belief in a 1:1-relationship between the two objects associated. obp.URL and obp.Contacts are dimensional tables (I assume/hope). Keeping the association in one different table requires one action if changes occur. In your model a change must be reflected in both those tables.

Here is an idea for such a table:

```
create table Contact_URL_match
   (ID int identity (1,1)
   ,URL_id int not null unique
   ,contact_id int not null unique
   ,created datetime)
```

the unique constraints disallow insertion of the same URL or the same Contact_id twice. On each insert/update prior content is being checked for duplicates and if found the action is denied, thus uniqueness protected.

For manifesting new matches in a first large initial action try this (haven't tested, just an idea)

```
INSERT INTO
  Contact_URL_match
    (URL_id
    ,contact_id
    ,created)
SELECT
  urls.id 
  ,contacts.contact_id      
  ,getdate()
FROM
  (SELECT 
    DISTINCT(contact_id)
    ,ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY contact_id asc) rn
  FROM 
    obp.Contacts) contacts
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT 
    id 
    ,ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY id) rn
  FROM 
    obp.URL) urls
ON
  contacts.rn=urls.rn
```

Within the subqueries this creates a row number in both the source tables based on the ORDER BY clauses. It then joins the resultsets of the subqueries by that rownumber which is an act of deliberate randomness. I hope you want that. The result of that join is inserted into the match table.

If later you want to manifest a single new association you could add WHERE clauses to the subqueries that specify what URL you want matched with what Contact. Before picking a URL or Contact check the match table with NOT EXISTS to make sure it is not used in there.

**EDIT :**  syntax errors cleaned

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the where clause issue... I knew it would be something like that! Thanks too for your suggestion. Will give that some thought.

Comment: happens to me every day. it's the little things... about match tables: very commonly used! Keep dimensional tables free of anything else and reference their content by use of IDs.